# ¿Que alternativas a cURL hay para hacer peticiones a una API en php?

Tags: php, api, curl

¿Alguien sabría una función similar al cURL para hacer peticiones a una API en php?

Hasta ahora he usado cURL para hacer peticiones http, pero me pidieron de investigar alternativas, por ejemplo para casos en que se trabaja en un entorno que no permite instalación de modulos, y cUrl no esta disponible, o si quizas existe una forma más ligera y menos compleja de hacer peticiónes simples.

Gracias

Comment: ¿Y qué tiene de malo curl?

Comment: @Carlangueitorm, el OP sabrá el porque quiere algo diferente a cURL, ahora bien, ahora bien OP, me parece una pregunta muy amplia.

Comment: Yo eh utilizado el cURL y me parece una buena opcion pero mi asesor me dijo que investigara otra forma de hacer peticiones

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar esta libreria

http://unirest.io/php.html

Ejemplo del mismo sitio

```
$headers = array('Accept' => 'application/json');
$data = array('name' => 'ahmad', 'company' => 'mashape');

$body = Unirest\Request\Body::json($data);

$response = Unirest\Request::post('http://mockbin.com/request', $headers, $body);
```

Saludos,

Comment: Yo he pensado en un proyecto a gran escala para reemplazar por completo Guzzle con Unirest. Se lo pediría a uno de mis compañeros de trabajo que recomienda Unirest. ¿Cómo puedo convencerlo?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar `file_get_contents()` pero solo te serviría para realizar las peticiones por *GET*.

Comment: ok, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Otra alternativa puede ser la extensión [`pecl_http`](https://pecl.php.net/package/pecl_http).

```
$url = 'http://api.sitioconservicios.com/servicios/cualquierwebservicio/';

$respuesta = http_post_data($url, $por_ejemplo_xml);
```